# iOS: Is it possible for UI objects to respect safe area without auto-layout in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, autolayout, uistoryboard

In my example, I have three buttons at the top of the `UIStoryBoard`. This works well for non-iphone x devices. However, it gets cut off when I use iPhone x. The buttons go above the safe area.

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible for the UIButtons to respect the safe areas without auto layout in storyboard? If not, how do I replicate this layout (UIButtons auto-resizing with flexible width and flexible height) with auto layout and respecting safe areas? I believe I should use aspect ratio on the UIButton's itself. Not sure if this is the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is easier than I thought. Just put all the UIButton's inside another view. Then add constraints to that view that respects the safe areas. This way the UIbuttons can still use autoresizing.

[Migrating a project using autoresizing masks for iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319388/migrating-a-project-using-autoresizing-masks-for-iphone-x)